# Process JSON with Jersey and Jackson

Tags: json, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jackson

I am using jersey in Java. I want to get JSON data sent via a post request. However, I am not sure how to do this, despite my searching. I am able to receive JSON data at a path, yet I can't figure out how to parse it into java variables. I assume that I need to use jackson to do this. However, I don't understand how to pass the received JSON to jackson.

```
@Path("/register")
public class ResourceRegister 
{
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String RegisterUser(//not sure what to take in here to get the json )
    {
        //code to deal with the json
    }
```

Comment: how are you forming request? do you get json string at UI side which you want to pass to your service?

Comment: correct. the user is sending info from the ui that will be sent as json. I want to receive this json in the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to place @JsonProperty annotation to your class properties and add that class to your Resource method as paramater.

You might need @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation as well if you are not deserializing everything inside the incoming json

See below:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String registerUser(MyUser myUser)
{
    //code to deal with the json
}


public class MyUser{
   @JsonProperty
   private String name;
   @JsonProperty
   private String surname;

 //getters & setters & constructors if you need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of accepting the JSON and using it in back-end.
1. set POJO elements using JAXB APIs and use object of that POJO class to access passed parameters. this will be helpful while JSON size is large.
Example:
your service declaration would be as following

```
@Path("/register")
public class ResourceRegister 
{
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String RegisterUser(RegParams regParams)
    {
        //code to deal with the json
    }
.....
}
```

and you will write a POJO like following

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonWriteNullProperties(false)
public class RegParams implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private long userId;

    @JsonProperty("userName")
    private String userName;
..
..
}
```

1. retrive JSON as a string and use jersey APIs to work with the same.
   in this case you can declare your service as following

   ```
   @Path("/register")
   public class ResourceRegister 
   {
       @POST
       @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
       public String RegisterUser(@FormParam("jsonObj")String jsonString)
       {
           //code to deal with the json
       }
   .....
   }
   ```

and you can process that string by using jersey APIs like following

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode mainNode = om.readTree(jsonString);
//access fields
mainNode.get..(as per data passed, string, int etc)
```

for more referance you can refer [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.17/json.html) or [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3a%22JacksonStreamingApi%22)